# Передаются пустые данные

Tags: php, html, mysql

Здравствуйте.

При редактировании данных передаются пустые данные. Как сделать, чтобы, например, если не выбран файл для загрузки, значение не изменялось в базе данных.

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    include_once '../inc/db.php';
    include_once 'header.php';
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $admin = new db();
    $game_ed = $admin->game_page($id);

    $catid = $_GET['catid'];

if($id>0){
    $game_edit = mysqli_fetch_array($game_ed);
  echo $game_edit['name'];
  $categ = $game_edit['categ'];
  ?>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <center>
     Name: <input type="text" name="name" size="12" value="<?php echo $game_edit['name'] ?>">
        </center>
        <center>Text <input name="text" size="200" value="<?php echo $game_edit['desc'] ?>"> </input>   </center>
        <center> Image : <input type="file" name="orig" size="12" value="<?php echo $game_edit['image'] ?>">   </center>
       <center> Slide : <input type="file" name="sl1" size="12"> <input type="file" name="sl2" size="12"> <input type="file" name="sl3" size="12">   </center>
       <center> Background <input type="file" name="back" size="12" value="<?php echo $game_edit['bg_game'] ?>">   </center>
       <center>Background Color <input type="text" name="bg_color" size="12" value=" <?php echo $game_edit['bg_color'] ?> ">  </center>
       <center>Logo <input type="file" name="logo" size="12" value=" <?php echo $game_edit['logo'] ?>">   </center>
       <center> URL <input type="text" name="url" size="12" value="<?php echo $game_edit['url'] ?> ">   </center>
       <center><input type="submit" name="sub" value="send"></center>

</form>
<?php
    if($_FILES){

     if(true === empty($_POST['name']))
       {

         }
         else {
             $name = $_POST['name'];
         }

            if(true === empty($_POST['text'])){

            }
         else {
            $text = $_POST['text'];
         }

        if(true === empty($_FILES['orig']['name'])){

        }
         else {
            $image = $_FILES['orig']['name'];
         }

                 if(true === empty($_FILES['back']['name'])){

                 }
         else {
            $background = $_FILES['back']['name'];
         }

                       if(true === empty($_POST['bg_color'])){

                       }
         else {
            $back_color = $_POST['bg_color'];
         }
                              if(true === empty($_FILES['logo']['name'])){

                              }
         else {
            $logo = $_FILES['logo']['name'];
         }
     $sl1 = $_FILES['sl1']['name'];
     $sl2 = $_FILES['sl2']['name'];
     $sl3 = $_FILES['sl3']['name'];
     $back_color = $_POST['bg_color'];
        if(true === empty($_POST['url'])){}
         else {
            $url = $_POST['url'];
         }

    if(isset($_POST['sub'])){
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['orig']['tmp_name'],"../image/game/game_img/".$image);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['back']['tmp_name'],"../image/game/bg/".$background);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['sl1']['tmp_name'],"../image/game/slider_game/".$sl1);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['sl2']['tmp_name'],"../image/game/slider_game/".$sl2);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['sl3']['tmp_name'],"../image/game/slider_game/".$sl3);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['logo']['tmp_name'],"../image/game/slider_game/".$logo);
    $admin->updategame($id,$name,$text,$image,$background,$back_color,$logo,$categ,$url);

    }
}
    }

else {
    $game_li = $admin->game($catid);
    while ($game_list = mysqli_fetch_array($game_li)){
        echo "<a href='?id=".$game_list['id']."'>".$game_list['name']."</a>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ох, как много кода ... Проверяйте, что все прошло успешно, иначе никак.

```
if(true === empty(...)) // - бесполезная конструкция. empty и так возвращает ТОЛЬКО bool значения
```

Заведите какую-то переменную ($continue = true) и проверяйте на каждом шаге ее. А в конце каждого шага ставьте ей false, если что-то пошло не так. И если в начале какого-то шага она false, то прекращайте выполнение кода. И **только** если все шаги завершены успешно ($continue == true), то пишите в БД.

Заговорился... Но в общем должно помочь.

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв. Все не должны быть заполнены. Т.е. могут быть и пустые, но должно не изменяться с базы значения,  @StixoTvorec

Answer (score 1):

Вам тогда нужно изменять метод

```
$admin->updategame();
```

Внутри этого метода проверять значения на пустоту и составлять запрос:

```
function updategame($name, $text)
{
   $set = "";
   if($name!='')
   {
      $set.= " name = ".$name.",";
   }
   if($text!='')
   {
      $set.= " text = ".$text,","
   }
   $sql = "UPDATE game SET ".$set." WHERE id = 5";
   DB::query($sql);
}
```

Это код, просто чтобы донести мысль, а не чтобы он работал.